# Python -- grouping consecutive elements satisfying a predicate

Tags: python, python-itertools

I would like to group consecutive elements satisfying a predicate. A doctest for such a function would look something like

```
>>> group([1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 6], lambda x: x != 0)
    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]] 
>>> group([1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 6], lambda x: x == 0)
    [[0], [0, 0]]
```

I have written a prototype where I use itertool's takewhile, but it's ugly because I keep casting between list and iter. I also don't want to stick to reading the indices of a list because it feels inefficient. Can someone point me how to mix and match the itertools together in the right way?

```
from itertools import takewhile

def group(l, p):
    blocks = []
    while True:
        i = iter(l)
        taken = list(takewhile(p, i))
        l = list(i)
        if len(taken) > 0:
            blocks.append(taken)
        if len(l) == 0:
            return blocks
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `itertools.groupby`?

Comment: Couldn't work out how to use it, but now I can. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
In [22]: import itertools as IT

In [23]: [list(g) for k, g in IT.groupby(
          [1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 6], lambda x: x != 0) if k]
Out[23]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> import itertools
>>>
>>> data = [1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 6]
>>> xs = [list(grp) for k, grp in itertools.groupby([1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 6], lambda x: x == 0)]
>>> xs
[[1, 2, 3], [0], [4, 5], [0, 0], [6]]

>>> xs[data[0] == 0::2]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
>>> xs[data[0] != 0::2]
[[0], [0, 0]]
```